# FreshWorks: Initiate a topic conditionally on FreshChat

Tags: node.js, nestjs, chatbot, freshdesk, freshworks

I'm trying to set up FreshChat Topics and I'm lost. I need the front end to send a few params (user type, screen) to the server through an API. Using these params I need to decide which topic to initialise. But I'm not sure how topics can be initiated from the backend. Do I call a specific FreshChat API to do this or is this done in a different way? These topics also need to trigger a bot which I guess can be setup in FreshChats SDK.